# how to create two responsive cell one below the other?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I need to have two cells equal in their height and they need to be one below the other.

the height of them should be change base on the windows size. (I know the windows size with js)

is there possible ? screenshot of the layout is attach.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I don't think your screenshot came through

Answer (score 2):

quite easy. just like this: http://jsfiddle.net/wuo6yyme/

```
html, body {height:100%}
.container {height:100%}
.div1, .div2 {
height:49%; 
width:100%; 
background-color:red;
}
.div1 {margin-bottom:2%;}
```